# Normal ditribution and proofs

Tags: probability

Can someone check my proof please?

Let $X~ N(\mu, \sigma^2 )$; use the symmetry of the density of X to suggest a transformation g such that Y = g(X) has the same density as X. (The identity transformation, $Y = X$, is not permitted).

X follows Normal distribution with mean µ and variance $\sigma^2$ X is symmetric about the mean $\mu$.
Because of this symmetry, the transformation $Y = -X $ will also have the same density as that of X.

Proof:

By Jacobian of transformations,

$$f(y)=f(x)\left | \frac{dx}{dy} \right |$$
$$\left | \frac{dx}{dy} \right | = 1 $$

The domain of X is -infinity to infinity.
Since Y=-X, the domain of Y is also -infinity to infinity.
So, Y also follow the same density of X.
Y follows Normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You have mis-understood the question. You have to come up with $g$ not equal to the identity function such that $g(X)$ has the same distribution as $X$. For this use the fact that $\frac  {X-\mu} {\sigma}$ has the same  distribution as $-\frac  {X-\mu} {\sigma}$ since $N(0,1)$ is symmetric. No add $-\frac {\mu} {\sigma} $ to both sides and multiply by $-\sigma$ to conclude that $2\mu-X$ has the same distributoion as $X$ so  $g(x)=2\mu -x$ does the job.